# Have three errors relate to expecting an element and unresolved references

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[related code for error in MainActivity.kt][2]

I have tried fn+option+return(Mac IOS) for import purpose, but still not working. Same as trying invalidate caches and restart. They are not working!
I just follow the lecture which is given by the professor step by step. The version for the Android studio on my macbook is 3.5.1
Looking for help.

I also met another error. Here is the code for the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.assignment3muyaozhang0882423" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".Floating_label" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >

        </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

The error I met which is sync error:
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in /Users/kitty/Downloads/Assignment2MuyaoZhang0882423/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/kitty/Downloads/Assignment2MuyaoZhang0882423/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 4; 元素类型 "manifest" 必须由匹配的结束标记 "" 终止。
Affected Modules: app

The code for app:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.assignment3muyaozhang0882423"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = kotlin_version
        targetCompatibility = kotlin_version
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

code for kt file:

```
package com.example.assignment3muyaozhang0882423

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.R
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG
import android.widget.Toast.makeText

class setion2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setion2)

        val usernamestring = text_Person_Name.text
        val passwordstring = text_Password.text
        val con_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.con_btn) as Button

        con_btn.isAllCaps = false
        con_btn.setOnClickListener {
            if (this.usernamestring.isNotEmpty() && this.passwordstring.isNotEmpty())
            {
                val message =
                    "User Name: " + usernamestring + "\n" + "Password: " + this.passwordstring
                Toast.makeText(this, message, LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid input", LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid adding your code as an image in your post.

Comment: ok, this is my first time to login stack overflow, so I don't know how to. Should I put the related code directly?

Comment: It's better if you copy-paste your code in your post directly. You can select your code and hit ctrl+k (windows) or cmd+k (mac) and that will format it accordingly. You have more chances of people replying and looking at your issue more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out my reply on your comment too.
Click on the error of text_layout and send the relevant code.

Comment: Currently, I met another error which is sync error. This leads to the design section can't be presented. How can I send my code to you?

Comment: At the end of line 12, you have put / before >. Remove the /> and put > at the end of application element.

Comment: Thank u very much! And I met the errors about Unresolved reference. And I will add the code  in my kt file. Could u help me to check it?

Answer (score 0):

It is LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

the underscore is missing between MATCH and PARENT

Comment: Thank you! That solve the error of expecting an element. How about Unresolved reference: text_layout? Thank you for your patient!

Comment: @MiaZhang Please click on the error and send me the line number of that error. Also send the code relevant to that.

If i solved your error, please give me a Vote Up